Is it true that any minimal surface has exactly one closed geodesic?
I heard this as an off-hand comment from a colleague and thought it was an incredibly strong result, but searching for anything like it on the internet later I found nothing. Can anyone point me a reference with this result or a similar one? Or, if it is false, give a counterexample?

As it stands, it's blatantly false. Consider all the minimal $S^2\subset S^3$.

Plane has no (nonconstant) closed geodesics. Are you sure your colleague knew what they were talking about?

Yeah, they might have forgotten to add compactness and euclidian ambient space

You should have known for years that there is no compact minimal surface in Euclidean space.

@TedShifrin sure, and I have known that for years indeed, but doesn't that only apply for three dimensional Euclidean space?

@TedShifrin I was wrong indeed. I thought somehow the argument for $\mathbb{R}^3$ wouldn't apply in higher dimensions, but any isometrical immersion of a compact manifold into Euclidean space, of any dimension, has a point where the second fundamental form is positive definite. Sorry!

back in $R^3$   the catenoid has one closed geodesic. However, the Riemann staircase example has a countable set, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%27s_minimal_surface  or   https://virtualmathmuseum.org/Surface/riemann/riemann.html

@WillJagy thanks! In that link you shared I see no mention of geodesics, could you explain why the example you gave has countably many closed geodesics?

No, there wouldn't be. The middle image in the virtualmathmuseum gives a good idea. Each layer is a sort of tube; indeed it is made up of circles in parallel planes, with a limiting straight line.  The closed geodesics I mention are one for each neck, in the same free homotopy class as the circle of smallest radius.

This came to me later:  each "neck"  of  the staircase example  is slanted: one may write down the ODE's  that express the radius $r(t)$ at height $t$  over the middle horizontal plane, as well as the displacement $c(t)$ of the circle centers. The point is that $c'(0) \neq 0.$ Simply taking the intersection of the staircase with a slightly slanted plane through  the center at height zero  gives a shorter curve than the circle of smallest radius, like unto an ellipse on a slanted cylinder containing that circle.
